# Extract File From Project After Published

Tags: .net, console-application, extract, publish

I have a .NET console application project with .NET 7 version, and I've published this project, resulting in only one .exe file for running the project. I added a .xml file to this project and want this .xml file to be copied to another directory when I run the .exe file. Please note that I only have one .exe file in the end, and there are no other classes or files alongside this file, so I can't use commands like `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

I want to add this functionality to the application by adding some code to the main project because after publishing the project, I don't have direct access to the files and complete code of the classes in the other project.This project only consists of one Program class and one XML file.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Do you want to copy an XML file from your project directory to somewhere else?

Comment: @keuleJ He is asking adding the xml file as an embedded resource and extract it at runtime which has many similar questions in SO

Comment: I have a console application project and I've created a publish with 'Produce single file' mode. Now, I want to add some code to my application so that the xml file I placed in the project copies to a specific path.